# "Do" question meaning

Tags: questions, do-support

"I go to school" question is "Do you go to school?"
I hear that using "Do/Does" question contains habit and recurring things like avobe.

Then, people in dramas often use "Do /Does" like what do we do? Where do I pay? But, in this case It doesn't look like asking usually recurring thing.

What is true? I'm a little confused. because I learned that Do/Does in present question sentence is used to ask people's habit or general things.

Comment: Consider them as "What to do?" and "Where to pay?"

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please go through this picture. I think you will understand.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please [edit] to include an explanation of how this image applies to this question. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta. Adding an explanation of this image in words will help learners find your answer when they search.